# Cannot get a subcription by id

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

After deletion of all subcriptions that i had, i cannot get any by it's id which is decalred in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http ie GET /subscriptions/{id}, and i'm retriving the folowing error:

```
Message: There was an error processing a storage extension.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-02-28T01:28:47
    request-id: d7a374b7-1cb7-426a-bcde-eb9658805bac
    client-request-id: d7a374b7-1cb7-426a-bcde-eb9658805bac
ClientRequestId: d7a374b7-1cb7-426a-bcde-eb9658805bac
```

There is a similar issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4644 but it's already closed.

More over this error is reported by Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException.StatusCode as NotFound !
So i think there is no subscription and going to add a new one in code above.

```
        public async static Task<Subscription> GetSubscription(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                return await graphClient.Subscriptions[id].Request().GetAsync();
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I'm not sure, if it's an GraphAPI bug, or i'm doing something wrong.

EDIT: By List of subcpriptions it's there
[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't put pictures like that on here. You just exposed your `ApplicationId` to the internet.

Comment: @RyanWilson it's ok, because it's just `Development AppId` and no secret 

Comment: Once you delete the subscription, you want retrieve it or access it or want to restore it? What are you planning to do. If you already deleted the subscription and tried accessing the error above sounds good - because its deleted, when you tried accessing it will report the error (i know the returned error is misleading)..

Comment: @Dev Sorry for misunderstanding, i meant just after deleting all subscriptions (and adding new one) i cannot get this new by id, but only by listing. But before deletion it was ok

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @OlegSkripnyak!! Yes you're correct - Before deletion it will work. Once you delete the existing subscription then its gone. You may see it for a while (may be due to caching), but its of no point calling or trying to use - because here the API just makes a call without knowing the resource exists or deleted. In the above scenario, the error returned is misleading (as the Graph service fails to find the subscription as it was deleted), but your assumption is correct (AFAIK, you're not doing wrong and the above is not bug either) its failing due to that.

Comment: @Dev Let me explain again. I had few subsciptions on the same resource and same secret, and i could access them by id, then i deleted both. Added a new subcription (and GraphAPI generated new id for me). Getting this subscription by this new id just brokes with this strange error, but this new subcription can be listed. Also if i try to get really missing subscription i get "Code: ResourceNotFound\r\nMessage: The object was not found....". Seems something was broken in my tenant ☹

Comment: You may be correct @OlegSkripnyak. But above you shared the different error. I would suggest you to wait for a while after creating subscription to see if it works for you. Or create a new token/call the API and see if it helps. If nothing works then its better to connect with Microsoft support to see if they have any insights to offer; just throwing a thought to consider. Prior to that, i would suggest you to try repro the issue outside of your code, may be in Graph explorer or POSTMAN as well.

Comment: @Dev Yes there is a different error: "Code: ExtensionError\r\nMessage: There was an error processing a storage extension..." but in GraphApi client ServiceException.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound. I was waiting for 3 days, and ofcourse tried few times with new token generated (it's a test project). Thanks for advice. I think to try on a different tenant. I can't use Graph Explorer because i've a subscriprion on a callRecord which can be accessed by App with CallRecords.Read.All only, but maybe PostMan with Fiddler intercepted token. Btw same behaviour in Graph Beta version